# C# Regex: Tag to Anchor Link

Tags: c#, regex, html, replace

I have custom tags that looks like this:

```
[document:13]text[document]
```

and

```
[item:2]texttext[item]
```

The *13* and *2* is the `id` and before `:` is the `type`.

So what I want to do is that all of these tags in a string will be replaced.

The first line will be replaced as `<a href="example.com/document?id=13">text</a>`

I'm currently trying `Regex.Match` however the `id` is a variable and could be anything and that's where I am stuck.

Cheers! :)

Comment: What would be the output for second one?

Comment: < a href="example.com/item?id=2">texttext< /a> @AvinashRaj :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

```
\[(\w+):(\d+)\]([^]]+)\[\1\]
```

And replace with

```
<a href="example.com/$1?id=$2">$3</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/tH6bV7/2)

Comment: Thank you! :) Where do you guys learn these expressions? Have Always had a hard time with them

Comment: @user3194181 mostly answering here and I found `regexr.com` to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in C#

```
var input = "[document:13]text[document]";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[(\w+):(\d+)\]([^\[]+)\[\1\]", @"<a href=""example.com/$1?id=$2"">$3</a>");
```